# NLog static GetCurrentClassLogger vs ILogger<HomeController> in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nlog

This example uses `ILogger<HomeController>` (see step 6):
[Getting started with ASP.NET Core 2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2)

What's the difference in that vs. using this static property in each `Controller`:

```
private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Performance and memory wise?